# Problems sub-classing a custom ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am writing an app where I need to create a custom ImageView (in order to override its onDraw). After failing to do that for a couple of weeks I created a minimal, reproducible example which captures the problem. Here is the code:

```
package com.nzeldes.mytestapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomImageView myImageView;
    Bitmap myBitmap;
 
    class CustomImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

        public CustomImageView(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int displaywidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(displaywidth, displaywidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        myBitmap.eraseColor(Color.BLACK);
        myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);  // Get a reference to the ImageView
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);                    // Associate the bitmap to the ImageView

    }
}
```

and the XML layout:

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="403dp"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>*
```

However, in the source window I get a “Unexpected implicit cast to CustomImageView: layout tag was ImageView” warning on myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
And if I try to run the app it crashes with this error from Logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to com.nzeldes.mytestapp.MainActivity$CustomImageView
```

I admit to being new to Android (putting the lockdown times to some use learning something new!)... any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inner classes the syntax becomes:

```
<view class="{package}.{ParentClass}${innerClass}"
```

Please change your layout like the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <view class="com.nzeldes.mytestapp.MainActivity$CustomImageView"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="366dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid that did not help. I replaced the XML as you suggested and the app crashes with:
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.nzeldes.mytestapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.nzeldes.mytestapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.nzeldes.mytestapp.MainActivity$CustomImageView

Any idea?

Comment: Use your class="{package}.{ParentClass}${innerClass

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand: how is 
class="{package}.{ParentClass}${innerClass} different from 
class="com.nzeldes.mytestapp.MainActivity$CustomImageView"  ?

Comment: The package name you found it on top of your main activity

Comment: Didn't work... same thing.  :-(  Will look for other wayas to get my task done. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: the simplest way is creating a Custom Image in separate class

Comment: You got it right! Making the proposed change to the layout XML and then moving the definition of the class CustomImageView to a separate file as a top level class (outside of class MainActivity) solved the problem. Thanks!